# How to order equalize eager loaded tables differently

Tags: sequelize.js

guys!
I have a table Todo and TodoItem, such that TodoItem is eager loaded into Todo. The Todo table contains a column 'id'; also, the TodoItem contains a column 'id' and 'content'. Now, I want to sort the Todo table with the id column and sort the TodoItem table with the content column. I have tried several ways as much as my knowledge can go, but I could only sort both tables with the same columns not with different columns... Any help will be most appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide some example data for tables `Todo` and `TodoItem` together with the desired result? And what exactly did you try already?

Comment: Thomas Fritsch, Thanks for the quick reply. However, below is my snippet I have done:

Comment: .findAll({
    include: [{
     model: TodoItem,
     as: 'todoItems',
    }],
    order: [
     [{model: TodoItem, as: 'todoItems'}, 'id', 'ASC'],
    ]
   })
  // Some other codes here

Comment: Can you update this in the question.. it's really difficult to read code from comments